# f_open directory name from variable

Tags: c, usb, directory, stm32

I'm using a STM32 microcontroller and I'm trying to write a file on an USB OTG drive.
I'm using the `f_open` function and it works fine like that

```
if(f_open(&fileW, "0:\\Folder\\INFO.TXT",FA_CREATE_ALWAYS | FA_WRITE) == FR_OK)
    { ...writing the file...
     }
```

What I want now is to write the file in a folder which name is in a variable.

I tried something like this:

```
if(f_open(&fileW, ("0:\\%s\\INFO.TXT", FolderName), FA_CREATE_ALWAYS | FA_WRITE) == FR_OK)
    { ...writing the file...
     }
```

And also like this:

```
uint8_t PathString[17] = {0};

sprintf(PathString,"0:\\%s\\INFO.TXT", FolderName); 
if(f_open(&fileW, PathString, FA_CREATE_ALWAYS | FA_WRITE) == FR_OK)
    { ...writing the file...
     }
```

I also tried to manually add `'\0'` in this second try but none of the ways work and I can't get into the `if` condition. What am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure `PathString[17]` is enough to store data?

Comment: @Jayesh yeah - would have to be a very small FolderName:)

Comment: Are you using `FatFs` API?

Comment: @Jayesh Yes of course dimension in enough :) and yes, I'm using FatFS

Comment: The first option is definitely not going to work. The second option allows for a folder-name of no more than 4 characters. Are you sure you're not inputting anything beyond that?

Answer (score 0):

Batter to use `snprintf`

```
int len = strlen(FolderName)+strlen("0:\\\\INFO.TXT")+1;
char PathString[len];
snprintf(PathString,len,"0:\\%s\\INFO.TXT", FolderName);
```

If you are using `FatFs` file system then you have to convert final string to `TCHAR` type
Like

```
TCHAR str[len], *t = str;
char *s = PathString;

while(*s)
 *t++ = (TCHAR)*s++;

*t = 0;
```

Then after go for `f_open`

```
if(f_open(&fileW, str, FA_CREATE_ALWAYS | FA_WRITE) == FR_OK)
{ 
  //do something 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn' know about this type conversion problem.
I'm doing some tests starting from your conversion (that I have to admit, I'm not fully understanding), but unfortunately it's not working and I'm still not going into the  if condition.

Comment: The best result I managed to obtain is writing
int len = strlen(FolderName)+strlen("0:\\INFO.TXT")+1;
and
snprintf(PathString,len,"0:\%s\INFO.TXT", FolderName);
eliminating 2 '\' from each line.
These creates a file in the root dir named "FoldernameINFO.txt" which means that the TCHAR conversion and the f_open function are somehow working, but I still don't know how to get the right folder path created.

Comment: Could it be a problem with the TCHAR char-to-char conversion of the "\\" (or I should say "\")?

Comment: Use of a VLA (`char PathString[len]`) is not recommended in this case (we're not even sure if OP is using C99 here).

Comment: And if OP was indeed using a wide-character string, then he/she could use `sprintf` with `"%ws"` instead of `"%s"`.